# What happens if a werewolf attempts to shape change in a tight space or while tied up?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, shapeshifting, werewolf-the-forsaken

I'm new to NWoD, I've played a bit of VTM and VTR, but my group is looking to play Werewolf the forsaken, I've read through the book a bit and the shape-shifting section, but didn't find an answer to this. what happens if say, a werewolf is handcuffed, or chained up, or is buried alive, or in a car... and they transform into gauru form and pack on 250 pounds and grow a few feet? Is there some check to see if whatever is restricting them is destroyed? is it destroyed automatically within reason? if its not reasonable, are they unable to transform? or if say, they are wrapped in chain do they attempt to grow, but the chains win and they just turn into werewolf jelly, squeeze through the links of chain before dying and reverting back to human jelly? I know they destroy clothing, but what if they are wearing some type of rigid tough armor?

I ask because I've got some players who love to try and break any system they take part in... if i say they can break out of chains etc... you can bet they'll run off the rails trying exploit this every chance they get. I can see them huddling in doorways or closets and all transforming at once to try and do structure damage.... stick halfway out a man hole and transform to destroy a road, crap like that.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Considering the transformation in NWoD is a fast process, the surge of physical size and strength would be able to get your players out of tight ropes and maybe weak chains, possibly break a closet door apart. However, if your werewolf doesn't have the physical strength to destroy a road while transformed, it won't be able to "explosively transform" into it. You must also take intent and movement when considering what can or can't be damaged during a transformation. If your PC is trying to break out of confinement while transforming, it adds its strength to the innate property of transforming but a band of werewolves standing transforming into a doorway simply to stand around may just push each other around into a suddenly confined space.

Transforming in exceedingly tight spaces may be painful, lethal or simply impossible but I believe this is left to the narrator's discretion and not ruled anywhere.

Comment: No better than the much-maligned prior answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the rules for breaking objects, using the Strength of the new form (+3 for Gauru).

An object with low durability (wooden door with 1 Durability) would break or bend to accomodate the new form of the player, but a object with high durability (reinforced concrete or steel) may not.

Instead of using 'damage to object' (as seem in World of Darkness Core p135), I'd use a simpler rule:

- If the new form Strength is higher than 2 * (object durability), the object breaks or bends or "makes way" for the Uratha;
- Otherwise, the Uratha takes crushing damage for the difference between the Strength vs Object Durability * 2.

Answer (score -4):

I'd say it depends on the surrounding material. Obviously a thin rope will simply snap, whereas a 1ft thick solid steel wall on both sides shouldn't budge. As a general rule of thumb I'd say anything the character's strength check is unable to overcome will not budge. The transformation may continue but you'd end up misshapen or crippled, with various implications on movement speed, constitution, strength and dexterity. I'd probably have them take crushing or bludgeoning damage as well, but allow them to shape back to normal without permanent disabilities. That should be enough of a deterrent while still allowing it to be used in legitimate and cool ways.

Comment: This answer is very opinionated ("I'd say...", "I would...", "general rule of thumb", etc).  It doesn't make any attempt to address the game's rules and it doesn't infer any experience with the game system.  It's generic enough that anyone who does or doesn't know the system could have written it.  We ask that if you answer questions subjectively, it be based on your own experience using those suggestions.